# PHP - hyperlink tag not showing full value of the variable

Tags: php

i am trying the following code in order to get the tag value to both in anchor and title. but code is ok with anchor text but showing only single char in title..

```
  $tag=$info['name']." from ".$info['city'];

  echo'  <td class="title1" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"> <a title='.$tag;  echo' href=details/';
  echo $info['friendly_url'];
  echo' >';
  echo $tag;
  echo'</a></td>';
```

please note that the tag value is something like  "David from NW";

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do not use "bgcolor" as attribute - it's obsolete. And as I can see are you using stylesheet classes anyway .. so you can use there the "background-color" attribute to give a backgroundcolor to the "td"-element..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need quotes around the `title` value, otherwise the parts after the space will be interpreted as a (malformed) HTML attribute.

```
echo '<td class="title1" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">';
echo '<a title="'.$tag.'" href="details/' . $info['friendly_url'] . '">';
echo $tag; 
echo'</a></td>';
```

It is good practice to use quotes to surround your HTML attributes to avoid situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

That is butt-ugly code. Repeated echoes get to be impossible to maintain in short order. You could use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) and make it pretty/legible at the same time:

```
echo <<<EOL
<td class="title1" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">
    <a title="$tag" href="details/{$info['friendly_url']}">$tag</a>
 </td>
EOL;
```

Any modern PHP-aware IDE will properly color the variables. And note how you can use quotes and variables within the heredoc, without having to do any nasty string concatenation.